# "one type is more general than the other" error in Rust while types are identical

Tags: rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping, rust-async-std, rust-futures

I have the following code

```
use std::future::Future;
fn main() {
    handle(Test::my_func);
}

fn handle<Fut>(fun: for<'r> fn(&'r mut Test) -> Fut) -> bool
where
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    true
}

struct Test {}

impl Test {
    pub async fn my_func<'r>(&'r mut self) -> () {
        ()
    }
}
```

Also, you can run it online on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=851b3bcf4eeb9e9fc637517357b3a858).

The following error appears:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:4:12
   |
4  |     handle(Test::my_func);
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
...
17 |     pub async fn my_func<'r>(&'r mut self) -> () {
   |                                               -- checked the `Output` of this `async fn`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: while checking the return type of the `async fn`
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Test) -> impl Future`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Test) -> impl Future`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Now, this is really weird because it clearly says that it's getting what it's expecting. I don't understand which type is more general than which. I don't understand lifetimes enough to debug this code. Could someone spare some more insight into this?

Comment: Type in the error message might be misleading: your async function is equivalent to `pub fn my_func<'r>(&'r mut self) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'r`

Comment: I found something that compiles but I'm not sure is what I want: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65c5b8032b4383f8352ee4a189e5a1e4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you can get a better error from the nightly compiler:

```
16 |     pub async fn my_func<'r>(&'r mut self) -> () {
   |                                               ^^ checked the `Output` of this `async fn`, found opaque type
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Test) -> impl Future`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Test) -> impl for<'r> Future`
```

In simple terms, this means that you expect `fun` to be a function which returns a struct implementing the `Future` trait, but with an implicit `+ 'static` bound, meaning the struct cannot have fields which are only alive as long as `'r`.

However, `Test::my_func` does want to refer to `&mut 'r self`, and because of that the program is rejected by the complier.

You could imagine something like `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Test) -> (impl Future + 'r)`, but this is currently not something that `rustc` accepts, and AFAIK there isn't any way to do this (without unsafe or boxing everything).

Depending on your use case, you might be able to get away with:

```
fn handle<'a, Fut>(fun: impl Fn(&'a mut Test) -> Fut) -> bool
where
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
{
    true
}
```

this works because we require a single lifetime (`'a`), which we can name for the `Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a` bound, instead of any lifetime (`for<'r> ..`) which we cannot name in that bound,
but this is a lot more restrictive.